# Bash comparison

Tags: bash, comparison, floating-point

I have a variable which stores the output of a command. How do I compare it with a float?

To be more specific I am doing

```
x=$(tail -n 1 foo| cut -d ' ' -f2)

if (($x < 0)); then ...
```

where `foo` is a filename. On doing the above I get the following error

```
-0.08 < 0 : syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is "0.08 < 0")
```

The value I need to compare is `-0.08`, but the error token is different

What should I do for such comparisons?

Answer (score 3):

bash doesn't support floating point arithmetics.
You can however use `bc` which is an external program to do arithmetics.

```
if (( $(bc <<< "$x < 0") )); then 
    printf "%f is less than 0\n" "$x"; 
fi
```

from the man page:

> The relational operators are
>
> ```
>   expr1 < expr2
>          The result is 1 if expr1 is strictly less than expr2.
>
>   expr1 <= expr2
>          The result is 1 if expr1 is less than or equal to expr2.
>
>   expr1 > expr2
>          The result is 1 if expr1 is strictly greater than expr2.
>
>   expr1 >= expr2
>          The result is 1 if expr1 is greater than or equal to expr2.
>
>   expr1 == expr2
>          The result is 1 if expr1 is equal to expr2.
>
>   expr1 != expr2
>          The result is 1 if expr1 is not equal to expr2.
> ```

---

one can also use `awk` that also supports floating point arithmetics.

Answer (score 0):

If ksh is available to you, you can use it to write your script instead of Bash since it supports floats. Zsh also supports floats.

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh
x=$(tail -n 1 foo| cut -d ' ' -f2)

if ((x < 0))
then
    echo "less than"
fi
```